# How to cycle / select between possibilities with tab key, in unix shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal, iterm2

I'm using iterm2 for the shell, on a mac, at school. And also using same tools at home. 
There is a discrepancy. When I have several choices using tab cycles between them. Let's say I have file1 file2 file 3 if I type vim [tab] I'll have the different files proposed at each keystroke, and I can select the one I want.
It doesn't work the same on my mac at home. Why? Shall I change my bash and how ? Shall I change settings and how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set this up with

```
bind TAB:menu-complete
```

You can see documentation on `menu-complete` by reading the entry in `man readline`.  We're binding the TAB key to `menu-complete` which will *"...step through the list of possible completions, inserting each match in turn."*